# Can't install Anthy

Tags: ibus

I installed Japanese in the Language Support, and then I went to iBus Preferences Input Method tab, selected "Customize active input methods" and then when I click Select an input method, I can only see China. Why there's no Japanese? iBus version: 1.4.1
OS: Linux Ubuntu 12.10
DE: Gnome-shell 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like Japanese Language Support doesn't included package **ibus-anthy**

1. **sudo aptitude search ibus-anthy** to findout the package status.

   the out put like this

   > **status** *package-name* description

   here is my output:

   [image]

   > **i**,  mean this package is already installed.
   >
   > **p**, meaning that no trace of the package exists on the system

   [more information about **aptitude**](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/rn01re01.html)
2. `sudo apt-get install ibus-anthy` to install the input Method.
3. Logout or restart ibus.